# How does viewport width work with font-size in css?

Tags: html, css, styling, viewport-units

Can someone help me understand how the viewport-width unit works with font size? In the documentation it says that 1vw = 1% of the viewport width (so 1% of the window width I guess?) but if I give my h1 a font size of 5vw it almost covers half of my page?

My question is basically how do u use this unit for font size? It works perfectly like you would imagine if you set the width of something but when you use it for font size it becomes gigantic?

Comment: font-size measures the *height*  of the font, are you aware of that?

Answer (score 1):

The formula for calculating the font size using vw is:

```
font-size: Xvw;
```

Here, X is a numerical value representing the percentage of the viewport width.

For example, if you set font-size: 4vw;, it means the font size will be 4% of the viewport width.

Here's a simple example:

```
body {
  font-size: 2vw;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 5vw;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Viewport width unit (vw) in CSS is actually a bit more complicated than font size. As you correctly mentioned, 1vw is equal to 1% of viewport width (visible area of ​​your website). So if your display area is 1000 pixels wide, 1vw would be 10 pixels.

For ex. this code ensures that font size of h1 starts at a base of 16px and grows proportionally to viewport width, but not as aggressively as using vw alone.

```
h1 {
    font-size: calc(16px + 2vw);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the screen is 1920 wide and you set `font-size: 5vw;` then the actual font size will be `5 * 1920 / 100` => `96px`